# tic-tac-toe using opencv but i can stopped when recognize game board

Tags: c, opencv, tic-tac-toe

Now I control robot to run tic-tac-toe game 
but i couldn't know how to use opencv library to recognize game board and inner square
I wonder how to use algoritm to get corner of game board and 9X9 Game square

This is what i do get the corner

Binary Image:

[image]

cvFindContours:

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(void){ 
IplImage *img=NULL;
IplImage *gray=NULL;
CvMemStorage* contour_storage;
CvSeq* contours=NULL;
CvPoint2D32f *corners;

img = cvLoadImage("tictactoe.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
gray = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );

cvSmooth( img, img, CV_GAUSSIAN, 3, 0, 0, 0);
cvCvtColor(img, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
cvAdaptiveThreshold(gray, gray, 128,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV, 3, 5);
cvNamedWindow( "Threshold", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage("Threshold", gray);

contour_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
corners = (CvPoint2D32f *)malloc(sizeof(CvPoint2D32f)*9);
cvFindContours(gray, contour_storage, &contours, sizeof (CvContour), CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));
cvDrawContours(img, contours, CV_RGB(255,0,0), CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2, 4, 8, cvPoint(0,0));

cvNamedWindow("Calibration", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage( "Calibration", img);

cvWaitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

i wonder how to process to image processing to perform game

This Progmram is limited to Using C Code and OpenCv 1.x to run embedded board using arm

Please let me know how to develop this game using opencv

Answer (score 2):

I only used the c++ interface up to now, so I don't know about the exact names of the functions you'll have to call. Nevertheless, here's a description of a rough algorithm I would use to achieve what you want, so you have a few keywords you can look up:

- As the camera image is clearly distorted, recognizable by the curved board lines, you should start by calibrating your camera. If you always use the same camera, or at least the same model with the same focal length, you'll only have to do this once. A quick tutorial on this can be found [here](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut10.html). [This](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html#cameracalibrationopencv) is a more detailed tutorial, with more mathematics, unfortunately he uses the c++ functions.
- The next step would be detecting the cells of your board. I think this can be achieved more easily by using a [Hough Line Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html?highlight=hough%20line) (also c++) and then calculating the line intersections and thus you can define your cells.
- If you want your software to automatically take it's turn, you can use a motion detector to determine if there's currently no motion and then act. Background subtraction is an easy way to do this. I didn't find a suitable explanation on this, just do a google search.
- After that you'll have to find circles and crosses. Circles are the easier part, as there's also a [Hough Circle Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html?highlight=hough%20circles). Crosses are more tricky. I would estimate the length of the crosses lines by taking the diagonals of your cells into account and the again use a Hough Line Detector.

Everything I mentioned here gets explained in detail (but not too theoretically) in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) book, which I found very helpful when learning OpenCV. They even use the C-Interface.